# How do I run in Bash under Atlassian Bamboo?

Tags: bash, continuous-integration, bamboo

I'm hosting my Bamboo on a Windows server and would like to run a script in Bash shell. I have learned that I could do that with in-line shebang. So I selected "Shell" as my interpreter and wrote the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
perl -pa ebin -s myapp start -detached
```

The failure report was as below:

> '#!' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

What was missing here?

Also, I tried to put the above script content in a batch file (.sh) to execute it with Bamboo Command. I put the file in the root directory and set the path of it on Bamboo as just the file name. Then the build just got broken there and there was no log displaying about it.

Any solution that would solve my problem is much appreciated!
(Bamboo version 6.1)

Comment: Are you saying you tried to run a `bash` script in windows? You can do this via several ways, given that the environment is setup accordingly. But I'm afraid shebang won't work, it is a `unix` specific thing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Lumio. According to Atlassian Bamboo release notes, it should have been enabled for shebang to work: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-13383

I have installed Git Bash on my server. But I couldn't apply it to my script under Bamboo. Could you please tell me how?

Comment: the referred ticket does not say it is implemented.

Comment: try adding system.os equals to linux in agent setting.